# Flutter-Google Maps API returns Null Autocomplete Predictions

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-maps-api-3

```
      Future<List<String>> getAutoCompleteResponse(String query)async{
      var prs=[];
      String key="<API-KEY>";
      final places = GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: key);

      PlacesAutocompleteResponse placesAutocompleteResponse = await places.autocomplete(query);
      prs = placesAutocompleteResponse.predictions.map((prediction)=>prediction.description).toList();
      print('Predictions: '+prs.toString());
      return prs;
    }

    TextField(
      showCursor: false,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search,color: Colors.blue,),
        suffixStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color: Colors.blue),
        hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color: Colors.blue),
        hasFloatingPlaceholder: true,
        alignLabelWithHint: true,
        hintText: "Type to Search",
        //border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))
    ),
      controller: textEditingController,
      onChanged: (query)async{
        predictions = await _geoService.getAutoCompleteResponse(query);
        setState(() {
        });
      },
    ),
```

I have attached the required code,

I have on textfield in which on every character i enter ,i query google maps for autocompletion,
Main issue which i am facing is lets take an example:

There is an exisiting address called as "Foo Apartments"

Now whenever i type ,'f' it suggest the predictions that start with 'f' and the moment i type 'o',there are no predictions eventhough they exist ,and the same thing happens even if i enter the exact name of the address,the worst case is consider there were predictions when i typed 'f' and after typing 'o' all the predictions are gone and now if i erase and the letter 'o',then also i get no prediictions.What could be the possible problems that i can look into to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got empty predictions only when there was some error code reported from map api,Every time i received empty prediction it had OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error,hence i activated the billing account and it worked as cheese.

If you get empty predictions i'm sure you are getting one of the error status code

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_responses